How to apply rolling windows with dynamically sized windows and custom functions on large datasets in Pandas?
I am working with a very large dataset (millions of rows) in Pandas on which I need to apply rolling window operations. However, the window size itself is not fixed and needs to change dynamically based on the values of another column. Additionally, I need to apply a custom aggregation function that involves multiple columns within each window.
Here’s an example of what I’m trying to do, but scaled down for simplicity:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    'Window_Size': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

The requirements are:

For each row, I want to calculate a rolling sum on the Value column where the window size is determined by the corresponding Window_Size value in that row.
Additionally, I need to apply a custom aggregation function within each window that considers both the Value and Category columns.

For example, within each rolling window, I want to calculate a weighted sum of Value but only for rows where Category == 'A'.
Problems:

Dynamic window size: The window size isn’t constant; it changes based on another column.
Custom aggregation: The custom function needs to operate on multiple columns and filter based on certain conditions within the window.
Performance: Given the size of my dataset (millions of rows), the solution needs to be optimized for performance. I’ve noticed significant slowdowns when applying groupby and rolling on smaller datasets already.

Questions:

How can I implement this dynamic, custom rolling window function efficiently in Pandas?
Should I consider moving to Dask or PySpark for performance reasons, and if so, how would I implement such logic in those frameworks?

Any guidance on both the Pandas implementation and the strategies for performance optimization with large-scale data would be highly appreciated.

nice question.  i posted an answer.  ps.  you are mixing snake case with camel case :) did you mean to ?

The starting point would be to create a function to implement and solve for the dynamic rolling, so here is a basic implementation that works:
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    'Window_Size': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to calculate rolling sum based on dynamic window size
def rolling_sum_dynamic(group):
    values = group['Value']
    window_sizes = group['Window_Size']
    result = []
    
    # Apply rolling sum with the window size specified by each row
    for i in range(len(group)):
        window_size = window_sizes.iloc[i]
        # Rolling sum for the current window size (look back `window_size` rows)
        sum_value = values.iloc[max(0, i - window_size + 1):i + 1].sum()
        result.append(sum_value)
    
    return pd.Series(result, index=group.index)

# Apply the function group-wise (by 'Category')
df['Rolling_Sum'] = df.groupby('Category').apply(rolling_sum_dynamic).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

# Output the result
print(df)

which produces this result:
  Category  Value  Window_Size  Rolling_Sum
0        A     10            1           10
1        A     20            2           30
2        A     30            3           60
3        B     40            1           40
4        B     50            2           90
5        B     60            3          150

what the question is asking next is, presumably, how to vectorise the above process (ie. remove the for loop which is a cause of inefficiency).
It would be interesting to see comments, but by dynamically changing the size of the rolling window, i would expect to lose the benefits (or ability to) of vectorisation, since the whole point is contiguous blocks of memory which any solution no longer has !!

Other alternative is to use numba:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit

data = {
    "Category": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    "Window_Size": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


@njit
def custom_rolling(categories, values, window_sizes, out):

    for i, w in enumerate(window_sizes):
        _from, _to = max(0, i - w + 1), i + 1
        # for example, sum only values where categories == 'A' (category code 0) in this window
        out[i] = np.where(categories[_from:_to] == 0, values[_from:_to], 0).sum()


df["out"] = 0
custom_rolling(
    df.Category.astype("category").cat.codes.values,
    df.Value.values,
    df.Window_Size.values,
    df.out.values,
)
print(df)

Prints:
  Category  Value  Window_Size  out
0        A     10            1   10
1        A     20            2   30
2        A     30            3   60
3        B     40            1    0
4        B     50            2    0
5        B     60            3    0


Quick benchmark on my AMD 5700x:
from time import monotonic

df = pd.concat([df] * 1_000_000)

start_time = monotonic()

df["out"] = 0
custom_rolling(
    df.Category.astype("category").cat.codes.values,
    df.Value.values,
    df.Window_Size.values,
    df.out.values,
)
print(f"{len(df)=:_} took {monotonic() - start_time}")

Prints:
len(df)=6_000_000 took 0.8775014060083777

